# jQuery animated message after form submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, forms, jquery-ui

I have a form and after user is successfully filled the form I want the actual message
to "bounce" from the top about 30px and show the actual message. The problem is that my
form's height is huge, about 900px so I'll never see the actual message unless I scroll on top of my page which is impossible because the page reloads itself after 3 seconds. How should I implement this? Here's my AJAX code for now:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

        // Process the form with AJAX
        $("form").on('submit', function(e) 
        {
            e.preventDefault();

                var from = $("form");

                $.ajax({

                    url: from.attr('action'),
                    type: from.attr('method'),
                    data: $(from).serialize(),
                    }).done(function(data) {


                    if(data.result == 0) {
                        $("#new_survey_success").hide();
                                for (var key in data.error) {
                                var value = data.error[key];
                                var output = '<p>' + value + '</p>';
                                }
                        $("#new_survey_error").fadeIn(1000).show().html(output);

                      }

                    if(data.result == 1) {

                        $("#new_survey_error").hide();
                        $("#new_survey_success").fadeIn(200).show().html("<p>" + data.success + "</p>");
                        window.setTimeout(function(){location.reload()},3000)

                      }
                }, 'json');



            return false;

        });
});

</script>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try position fixed instead of absolute.

Comment: Try using [Alertify](https://fabien-d.github.io/alertify.js/). Does exactly what you want.

Comment: This is a CSS issue. Just use position fixed and set the location you would like it to be displayed at.

Comment: Techincaly yes, but I also asked about the animation effect. I want the message box slide from top of the page to about center of the page.